# Creating Additional Relational Tables in Oracle for WSO2 Governance Registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Our WSO2 Governance registry is pointing to external Oracle Database and apart from the Default tables created by running Oracle.sql script given by WSO2, we also need to create some additional relational tables in Oracle. For this need we are not finding any articles in GREG Documentation. Kindly clarify us if we are allowed to create additional relational tables and if so how do we go about it?
Note: GREG V5.3 & Oracle 11G

Thanks

Comment: What you're trying to do is not clear. Are you going to customize Greg?

Comment: To be precise, We are making GREG API (Governance) calls and it stores data in the Oracle DB tables created by running Oracle.sql but we want to create one additional table where we want to store data comes through GREG API's.

Comment: Awaiting for the valuable inputs.Kindly respond.

Comment: You create Reg tables by running `<CARBON_HOME>/dbscripts/oracle.sql` script manually. So why can't you create the new table the same way? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: We are aware about running oracle.sql script but the concern is will we be able to create a new table by making an entry in the script? If so is that sufficient and no configurations required at any other place? and can you assure that when adding a resource through Publisher UI/ GREG API's, will eventually go and sit in the newly created tables in database?

Comment: If you add a new table to the script and run the script, yes it will create the table. But how do you expect the new table to get filled? Are you going to write some code? I'm totally confused.

Comment: That is what we are looking for. We want to create additional tables and want to know how to store values in it and what are the changes(code/config wise) required? I hope my posted question is clear and kindly revisit if it's confusing for you.

Comment: It'll be great if you can explain why you need an additional table.

Comment: Sure. Here it is. Generally GREG stores all the values as BLOB content in REG_CONTENT table but we want to separate few values and store it in our additional tables for classification purposes.

Comment: That's going to need some code changes. No one will be able to directly answer your question. You'll have to go through the code and figure it out.

Comment: Alright! Thanks Bhathiya. Can you let me know how to go about it to meet our requirement? Especially would like to know what code to look for changes ? I hope we need to build and deploy after code changes